# RoR routes.rb - All to root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm learning RoR on the side and I've decided to duplicate my current site (built w/ PHP/WP) to the exact functionality (or as best as I can).

I have a Projects model and each has their own 'show' page. I also have a Pages controller which routes all URLs to root as a slug. ie: /test-page, /about, /contact

But is there a way I can also point the projects slug to "root"? So it would be: /project-name1, /project-name2 etc instead of /projects/:slug?

I'm new to Ruby and RoR so I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious. The only way I can see how to do this, for now, is to write a controller to pull in the proper controller for the slug type based on a slug-matching system. So if /page matches in a Page model, it uses that template. Otherwise, a project.

It seems wrong and I'm not even sure if I can direct controllers like that anyway?

---

Came up w/ this.. but it seems incomplete?

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

class SiteController < ApplicationController
    attr_accessor :project, :page

    def show
        check = -> m { m.where(:title => params[:slug]).first }

        if (@project = check.call(Projects)).present?
            render 'projects/show'

        elsif (@page = check.call(Pages)).present?
            render 'pages/show'

        else
            raise ActionController::RoutingError.new 'Not Found'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: This really does not look like what a Rails controller should look like.

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're saying you want two models to be utilized within one controller - as in 'projects' and 'pages' are effectively the same thing as far as routing is concerned. Can you tell me why it's important you do it this way? What's wrong with a URL like `imadesigner.com/portfolio/some-other-company-project`?

If you really want to mix projects in with regular site pages as far as a URL scheme goes, then there are some 'workarounds'. When I got started with RoR I was also coming from PHP. I originally used `pid` and `sid` variables in my URL structure to delineate page structure and I brought that mindset over to RoR. It didn't really work out. As far as 'static' site pages go, what's wrong with mapping a static string to a controller/method?

i.e.,

Instead of thinking of it as: `imadesigner.com/:could_be_either_a_project_or_page`, explicitly write the routes as:

```
get '/contact', to: 'site#contact'
get '/set-me-on-fire', to: 'site#burninate'
get '/:id', to: 'site#projects'
```

This way you explicitly set static routes BEFORE your projects slug match. Any request to `imadesigner.com/contact` is sent to `site#contact`, requests to `imagedesigner.com/set-me-on-fire` are sent to `site#burninate` and ANYTHING ELSE is considered a search for a project which executes the site#projects method. So now within your projects method you don't need to determine whether or not the request is searching for a page or a project; it's always searching for a project.

All this considered, you're still going to have problems because you need to make sure your project slugs don't interfere with regular page slugs; otherwise one model will take precedence over the other and you will have an inaccessible page/project.

Comment: This works, just makes adding additional pages a little messier than I was hoping for. But I think this is it. Thank you!

Comment: Moreover - you should consider the answer given in your Reddit post as well. You should keep your controllers/methods discrete to their purpose. So you could make a 'StaticPagesController' which houses the methods required by all your static pages, and you could store your html templates in app/views/static_pages/whatever.html.erb for easier management instead of housing *everything* in the SiteController. If one of those static pages does more than just show paragraphs of text (i.e., it involves models), you can move it into it's own controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the root url to `project#show`. Like:

```
get '/:id' => 'product#view'
```

Comment: But this will override setting 'pages' to root?

Comment: Yes, it will. You cant map multiple actions to a single route.